# Realtek RTL8723BE Card Wifi hard blocked after waking up from suspend in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wifi-hardware-switch

I have been facing this problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for over an year now and somehow there seems to be no fix online! Wifi appears to be hard blocked after the laptop wakes up from suspend. The only fix is restarting the laptop every time and that's annoying. I really want to quickly get back to my work and not restart my laptop every time. The wireless card is RTL8723BE.

Comment: What happens if you restart network-manager instead of the laptop?

Comment: No effect! Wifi stays hardblocked. Restart is the only available fix as of now, and its been more than a year

Comment: See if you find this discussion useful: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/124

Comment: I've gone through the entire discussion multiple times already. No effect! I'll keep trying. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

On 16.04, I see this after suspend too. But I don't need to reboot. I can just reload the kernel module (driver):

sudo modprobe -rv r8723bs && sudo modprobe -v r8723bs

Not required to restart network-manager or nm-applet.

I use kernel 4.14.7 & 4.15.7 on a Lenovo ideapad 100S.

Newer kernels can be found in mainline ppa, eg:
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.7/